# Split the numeric string column in to multiple columns after each comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

[image: split the string in multiple columns in a table for multiple columns. like i got this output from string aggregation]
I need to convert this in to three columns, length is not static since above numbers are coming based on calculation.

Comment: What do YOU mean by "derived column"?  Is this some sort of string?  How is it produced?

Comment: those values came from string aggregation using  stuff and xml functions

Comment: It would almost certainly be easier to do this operation *before* you aggregate...

Comment: may be, but my requirement made me to do this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because an unformatted statement of requirements is not a suitable question for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2016 you can use `STRING_SPLIT` to split the string (once you remove the surrounding `(` and `)`) and then `PIVOT` that result to columns:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE('(0.0000, 3546.0000, 253422.000)', '(', ''), ')', ''), ',')
)
SELECT [1] AS Val1,
       [2] AS Val2,
       [3] AS Val3
FROM CTE
PIVOT (
  MAX(value)
  FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3])
) p
```

Output:

```
Val1        Val2        Val3
0.0000      3546.0000   253422.000
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7f7a2cd4f588bf7dcb476a8c1f77f161)

To do this with values in a table, you just need to `CROSS APPLY` the `STRING_SPLIT` to the table inside the `CTE`. For example, if the column is called `exclusion` in a table called `data`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT exclusion, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY exclusion ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
  FROM data
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(exclusion, ',')
)
SELECT exclusion,
       [1] AS Val1,
       [2] AS Val2,
       [3] AS Val3
FROM CTE
PIVOT (
  MAX(value)
  FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3])
) p
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=55c04b4db90839152ea4ed66eecab568)

Comment: thanks for the response, actually i do not have braces it just as commas. sorry for the confusion

Comment: @sql2020 no worries - if no braces you can simply remove the two calls to `REPLACE`

Comment: actually this answer is only working for static values or just one row, i need to spin for the entire table, can you please help  me

Comment: @sql2020 what is the table and column name?

Comment: exclusion and columns like exclusion1, exclusion2,,exclusion3,we wil have only max 3 values, so we can get up to 3 columns

Comment: @sql2020 Sorry I meant the column name which contains the comma separated strings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212749/discussion-between-sql2020-and-nick).

Comment: Attention: `STRING_SPLIT()` ist not guaranteed to return the expected sort order. better use OPENJSON and deal with the string as a JSON array. Otherwise you might get correct results in all your tests, but break in production with silly errors...

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs `STRING_SPLIT()` is not guaranteed to return the expected sort order.

> The output rows ***might be in any order***. The order is not guaranteed to
>   match the order of the substrings in the input string.

Read this here: [STRING_SPLIT() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Try this JSON approach:

```
DECLARE @yourString NVARCHAR(100)=N'0.0000, 3546.0000, 253422.000';
```

--simply return the array as derived table

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'[',@yourString,']'))
```

--use implicit pivoting by using a WITH clause (needs doubled array brackets)

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'[[',@yourString,']]'))
WITH (val1 FLOAT '$[0]'
     ,val2 FLOAT '$[1]'
     ,val3 FLOAT '$[2]')
```

### UPDATE

Here I use the sample of your other question. Please - for your next question - do not poste a picture. Nobody wants to type in the values.

Best is DDL and INSERT as I do it here:

--Define a *mockup table* to simulate your issue and insert sample data

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,[TYPE] VARCHAR(100),prouctValues VARCHAR(100),subproValues VARCHAR(100),Amount VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (23844,'12, 19','0.0000, 0.0000','0.0000, 0.0000','0.0000, 0.0000,37464.083')
,(25397,'1, 3,26','0.0000, 0.0000,2.345','0.0000,0.2345, 0.0000 ','25455.6800, 0.0000');
```

--The query

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,AllTypes.*
      ,AllPvals.* 
      ,AllSPvals.* 
      ,AllAmts.*
FROM @tbl t 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[[',t.[TYPE],']]'))       WITH(t1      INT           '$[0]'
                                                           ,t2      INT           '$[1]'
                                                           ,t3      INT           '$[2]') AllTypes
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[[',t.prouctValues,']]')) WITH(pval_1  DECIMAL(10,4) '$[0]'
                                                           ,pval_2  DECIMAL(10,4) '$[1]'
                                                           ,pval_3  DECIMAL(10,4) '$[2]') AllPVals
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[[',t.subproValues,']]')) WITH(spval_1 DECIMAL(10,4) '$[0]'
                                                           ,spval_2 DECIMAL(10,4) '$[1]'
                                                           ,spval_3 DECIMAL(10,4) '$[2]') AllSPVals
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[[',t.Amount,']]'))       WITH(amt_1   DECIMAL(10,4) '$[0]'
                                                           ,amt_2   DECIMAL(10,4) '$[1]'
                                                           ,amt_3   DECIMAL(10,4) '$[2]') AllAmts;
```

The result

```
+-------+----+----+------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------+------------+
| ID    | t1 | t2 | t3   | pval_1 | pval_2 | pval_3 | spval_1 | spval_2 | spval_3 | amt_1      | amt_2  | amt_3      |
+-------+----+----+------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------+------------+
| 23844 | 12 | 19 | NULL | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | NULL   | 0.0000  | 0.0000  | NULL    | 0.0000     | 0.0000 | 37464.0830 |
+-------+----+----+------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------+------------+
| 25397 | 1  | 3  | 26   | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 2.3450 | 0.0000  | 0.2345  | 0.0000  | 25455.6800 | 0.0000 | NULL       |
+-------+----+----+------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: Ok, actually i need spin it across table for almost 5 columns containing comma separated strings. So the out put should return 15 columns(15*3). Also, the table returning more than million rows

Comment: @sql2020 so please provide a more realistic [mcve]. You might concatenate all csv strings and take them as one big array. This approach works against a table with `apply`.

Comment: I have edited the question with example, please look in to it.

Comment: @sql2020 please provide the output for this new input

Comment: @sql2020, sorry, this is not clear. Please try to provide both sample and output in a tabular format including datatypes. Best was to provide DDL and INSERT to create a working, *stand-alone* [mcve]. Your question sounds like the need to split a string, but your input suggests something else...

Comment: Added image with input and output format. please look in to it. thanks!!

Comment: I don't understand the need for the 2nd question.

Answer (score 0):

String operations are painful in SQL Server.  Here is one method:

```
select replace(v1.el, '(', '') as column1, v2.el as column2,
       replace(v2.rest, ')', '') as column3
from t cross apply
     (values (left(t.derived, charindex(',', t.derived) - 1),
              stuff(t.derived, 1, charindex(',', t.derived), '')
             )
     ) v1(el, rest) cross apply
     (values (left(v.rest, charindex(',', v.rest) - 1),
              stuff(v.rest, 1, charindex(',', v.rest), '')
             )
     ) v2(el, rest);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but cross join affecting performance since we are dealing more than 10 million rows

Comment: @sql2020 . . . That should be `cross apply`.  But either way, there is really no impact on performance when there is only one row in the second table.