# Split the column in to three columns for each input column based on comma

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Input:

```
  ID      TYPE      prouctValues            subproValues                Amount
23844   12, 19     0.0000, 0.0000           0.0000, 0.0000          0.0000, 0.0000,37464.083
25397   1, 3,26    0.0000, 0.0000,2.345     0.0000,0.2345, 0.0000   25455.6800, 0.0000
```

I need to convert this in to three columns
output:

```
id      t1  t2  t3   pval_1 pval_2 pval_3 Spval_1 spval_2 spval_3  amt_1   amt_2   amt3
23844   12  19  null 0.0000 0.0000  null  0.0000  0.0000  null    0.0000  0.0000  364.083
25397   12  03  26   0.0000 0.0000  2.345 0.0000  0.2345  0.0000  254.680 0.0000  null
```

Comment: If multiple values are being shoe-horned into one column, create separate columns.

Comment: input came from different source, i need to convert in to output format.

Comment: is there a maximum number of possible values ? Like what you have shown here is 3 ?

Comment: Yes, total 3 and 3 for each column

Comment: This is the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61492850/5089204). It was better to improve the existing question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a known or maximum number of columns AND open to a HELPER function.

**Example**

```
Select A.ID 
      ,t1     = B.Pos1
      ,t2     = B.Pos2
      ,t3     = B.Pos3
      ,pval1  = C.Pos1
      ,pval2  = C.Pos2
      ,pval3  = C.Pos3
      ,spval1 = D.Pos1
      ,spval2 = D.Pos2
      ,spval3 = D.Pos3
      ,amt_1  = E.Pos1
      ,amt_2  = E.Pos2
      ,amt_3  = E.Pos3
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Col]([TYPE],',') B
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Col]([prouctValues],',') C
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Col]([subproValues],',') D
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Col]([Amount],',') E
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Col] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
    From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
)
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you John.

Comment: Always happy to help